# Cannot locate the my.cnf file in MySQL 8.0 running on Windows 10

Tags: mysql, remote-access

I am attempting to change the bind address in the my.cnf file so that I can allow the database to be accessed remotely, but I cannot locate the file on my Windows 10 machine.  I am running MySQL 8.0

The path that I have searched is C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Mysql hides in a hidden folder `ProgramData`

```
C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0
```

And windows uses

```
my.ini
```

not my.conf